# How calculate stopping distance from velocity and cheat's friction

Tags: javascript, 2d, physics

I'm implementing a 2D physics game.
Suppose we have `vx` as our velocity, and every game update we apply friction like this -

```
vx *= 0.99 // incredibly low friction.
```

How would I calculate the distance covered from our initial velocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a while loop to sum the distance traveled as the object slows down, we sum for each iteration of the loop.

It's worthwhile pointing out that the object will *never* completely stop, but the distance traveled will reach a limit.

We can use a velocity threshold to decide what we consider as stopped.

```js
const friction = 0.99;
const stoppedVelocityThreshold = 0.001;

let velocity = 100;
let distance = 0;

while (velocity > stoppedVelocityThreshold) {
    distance += velocity;
    velocity *= friction;
}

console.log('Final Distance:', distance)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

We can also view distance as an infinite geometric series of the form:

```
a + ar + ar² + ar³ ...
```

Where a = Initial velocity and r = friction.

The sum of this series is given by:

[image]

then use this to sum the distance after `count` steps.

This will converge to:

[image]

Distance after N steps:

```js
const velocity = 100.0;
const friction = 0.99;
const input = [10, 100, 1000, 10000];

for(let n of input) {
    const distanceAfterNSteps = velocity * (1 - Math.pow(friction, n)) / (1 - friction);
    console.log(`Distance after ${n} steps:`, distanceAfterNSteps .toFixed(3))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Final distance:

```js
const velocity = 100.0;
const friction = 0.99;

const finalDistance = velocity / (1 - friction);
console.log('Final distance:', finalDistance.toFixed(3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! it works nicely!